# Why has my question been closed as "Opinion Based"?

Tags: discussion

Why has [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592752/why-are-just-and-justice-written-like-that) been closed as “opinion based”? What did I put in the question that is making it an opinion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not to me look like you were asking for people's opinions. I imagine you consider this a matter of fact, not opinion. It is possible that the close voters consider it only a matter of opinion, not of fact. But I do not know this for certain.

At least two of the three close voters will have to have voted that way. They're the only ones who know why they voted that way.

But as written your question is nonetheless a little unclear and unresearched. It's unclear because there are dozens of such words but you only thought of two, and because asking why we don't spell *just* the same way that we spell *gust* is a deeply confusing question of itself.

So it feels like you are unaware of two thousand years of intervening history  between classical antiquity and today's spelling. Or even the history of the letter J as in [*Gaius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius) [*Julius Caesar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julii_Caesares) — not to mention C as in *Gaius*, and yes, Latin also didn't have a G for the longest time, so C is the abbreviation for *Gaius*.

It's unresearched, or at least shows no research, so we don't know where to start. We don't know what you know or don't know, because you haven't shown your research.

In any event, that's way too much of an open-ended question for our format here to cover.  Books are written about this.

So your question is still very hard for us here to answer in a satisfactory fashion.

Comment: If the OP knew how to ask the question the right way, then they'd probably be able to answer the question for themselves. There are lots of 'why' questions that one can ask about English orthography and many of them are answerable, even if it is simply 'we don't know'. This kind of question is exactly the kind that is interesting for language enthusiasts.

Comment: I cannot answer for the closers. I cannot answer the original question because it requires a vast knowledge of consonant and other shifts over centuries. I know an academic linguist who could have answered rigorously within the bounds of contemporary knowledge. In principle the question therefore should not have been closed. In practice, the question deals with a tiny part of linguistics that touches on a huge area of linguistic theory that is inevitably tinged with opinion despite the rigour of approach. It asks too much of us.